# Wire shark not capturing any packets

Tags: linux, wireshark

I have a windows 10 version 1809 host machine running Kali Linux on VBox. I have the VBox network setting set on NAT and Ive also tried a bridge network but wireshark will not capture a single packet, what is wrong?

Comment: Wow I actually just fixed it, set the network adapter to bridged but changed it to wireless instead of ethernet

Comment: You can also just download Wireshark for Windows if you want to capture traffic. Also, contrary to what you read on some blogs, Kali is not "what all the hackers use". Kali is for [penetration testing](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/399626/why-is-kali-linux-so-hard-to-set-up-why-wont-people-help-me), and using it in a VM has lots of known issues. Get a proper Linux distribution and you'll have all the hacking tools Kali has, but none of the trouble.